# Chrome extension: browser.runtime API results in "browser is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension and want to access a background script global variable from the content script, so I'm using the [browser runtime API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime) to pass messages between the content and background scripts.

This results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined" 
[Image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH91B.png)

- content script:

  ```
  //alert for debugging purposes
  alert("content.js is loaded.");


  document.body.onLoad = sending;

  function sending(){
      //alert for debugging purposes
      alert("content.js is loaded, and sending() has been called.");
      //sends a Promise to the receiver
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          browser.runtime.sendMessage({
              type: "getText"
          }).then(function(message) {
                alert("Value of text is: ", message.result);
          });
  }
  ```
- background script:

  ```
  //alert for debugging purposes
  alert("background.js is loaded.");

  //'text' is the variable I'm trying to access from content script.
  var text = prompt("Why are you here on this page?","E.g: To watch Daniel Schiffman's first video.");

  //add a listener for the message sent from the content script
  browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.type == "getText") {
              //alert for debugging purposes
          alert("browser.runtime is working from background.js");
              //send the response to content script
        sendResponse({result: text});
      }
  });
  ```

**Notes**

- I have tried replacing all appearances of `browser.*` with `chrome.*`. The error message disappears, but the `alert`s inside the browser.runtime functions don't appear when I refresh the page, meaning the sendMessage() and onMessage() did not execute.
- Seeing other advice from Stack Overflow, I also tried this: `var browser = browser || chrome;`, which is essentially the same thing as above.
- Both background.js and content.js have been added to my manifest.json

Comment: Chrome extensions don't have `browser`, which is only for WebExtensions. Chrome extensions are not WebExtensions and they only have `chrome`, which is callback-based. The [documentation is different](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) as well. In your case you need the [polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) or rewrite the code to use `chrome` and callbacks instead of Promise.

Comment: You are looking to use `chrome` instead of `browser`. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime. 

Also as mentioned by @wOxxOm above, it is a callback-based and not a promise so I don't think you can just use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(..).then()`

Answer (score 0):

You need the types for the `chrome` global object.

You can obtain them auto-magically by installing the package `@types/chrome`.

I personally prefer `yarn` but `npm` will do it as well.

```bash
yarn add @types/chrome
```

Use `chrome` not `browser`, whether in Firefox or Chrome, the APIs are the same as far as I've explored them.

The API [documented by google](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference) will work on firefox and chrome - to my limited knowledge - but if you refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) it will be the same except that you use `chrome` instead of `browser` as the object to operate on.